# aClassic ASP : How to locate an specific order in array, or record-set. Then move Next or Previous, starting from that order

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic, ado, recordset

I have done a bit of work on my code, and still unsure about how some of the code needs to be done in order to work.

So far I got a function named FunctionUp' coded, this is the code that will go in the following sequence:

If array of orders contains:

```
'A1G722
'A1G723
'A1G724
'A1G725
'A1G726
'A1G727
```

I added a reference to the current location as a query-string parameter named rowindex, so if the order passed in query-string is 'A1G725', the row index value will be 4, then function code will ideally browse in this sequence: 'A1G725', 'A1G724', 'A1G723', 'A1G722'

The code for the button:

```
.Write "<input type='submit' name='btnUp' value='Next' class='buttonRight' />"
```

The code that calls the function:

```
If Request("btnUp") = "Next" Then Call FuctionUp()
```

The code for the function:

```
Function FuctionUp()
    Dim objConn
    Dim objRS
    Dim SQLOrderList
    Dim SQLCurrentOrder 
    Dim currentorder     
    Dim previousorder
    Dim sortby 
    Dim dtstart
    Dim dtend
    Dim index 

    currentorder = Trim(Request.QueryString("order"))
    sortby = Request.QueryString("sortby")
    currentorder = Request.QueryString("order")
    dtstart = Request.QueryString("start")
    dtend = Request.QueryString("end")

    Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    objConn.Open Application("conn_AWDSTAGE")
    objRS.Cursortype = 3    

    SQLOrderList = "SELECT orderno" & _
                    " FROM _order" & _
                    " WHERE order_date >= '" & dtstart & "'" & _
                    " AND order_date < '" & dtend & "'" & _     
                    " ORDER BY " & sortby    
    objRS.Open SQLOrderList, objConn

    index = CINT(Request.QueryString("rowindex"))

    If Not isNumeric(index) Or index = "" Then 
        index = 0 
    End If 

    'Get this to Array.
    Dim iArray
    Dim i
    Dim sizeOfiArray
    iArray = objRS.GetRows()    

    ' sample of array contents after sql execution
    'A1G722
    'A1G723
    'A1G724
    'A1G725
    'A1G726
    'A1G727

    sizeOfiArray = uBound(iArray) + 1    
    if not index >= (sizeOfiArray - 1) then previousorder = (index + 1)

    If Not previousorder Is Nothing Then
        Response.Redirect("~/printpreview.asp?order=" & previousorder(i) &
                            "&site=" & spiderSiteKey &
                            "&env=" & strEnv &
                            "&start=" & CDate(dtstart) &
                            "&end=" & CDate(dtend) &
                            "&rowindex=" & (index + 1) &
                            "&sortby=" & sortby)
    Else
        Response.Redirect("~/printpreview.asp?order=" & currentOrder.OrderID & 
                            "&site=" & spiderSiteKey &
                            "&env=" & strEnv &
                            "&start=" & CDate(dtstart)) &
                            "&end=" & CDate(dtend) &
                            "&rowindex=" & (index) &
                            "&sortby=" & strSortBy &
                            "&LastRecord=Up")
    End If

    objRS.Close()
    Set objRS = Nothing
    objConn.Close()
    Set objConn = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What is the conversation between the user and the system? Could you explain what printpreview.asp is doing - does it display a single order or multiple orders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier simply to get the next or previous orders directly from the database using SQL:

```
sSQLGetPrevOrder = "SELECT top(1) PREV.* " _
                & " FROM [Order] PREV " _
                & " JOIN ( " _
                &   " SELECT " & strOrderBy & " sortvalue, orderno " _
                &   " FROM Order WHERE orderno='" & strCurrentOrder & "' " _
                &   " ) CURR " _
                &   "  ON PREV." & strOrderBy & " < CURR.sortvalue " _
                &   "     OR ( PREV." & strOrderBy & " = CURR.sortvalue " _
                &   "            AND PREV.orderno < CURR.orderno ) " _
                & " ORDER BY PREV." & strOrderBy & " DESC, PREV.orderno DESC "




 sSQLGetNextOrder = "SELECT top(1) NXT.* " _
                & " FROM [Order] NXT " _
                & " JOIN ( " _
                &   " SELECT " & strOrderBy & " sortvalue, orderno " _
                &   " FROM Order WHERE orderno='" & strCurrentOrder & "' " _
                &   " ) CURR " _
                &    " ON NXT." & strOrderBy & " > CURR.sortvalue " _
                &    "    OR ( NXT." & strOrderBy & " = CURR.sortvalue " _
                &    "         AND NXT.orderno > CURR.orderno ) " _
                & " ORDER BY NXT." & strOrderBy & " ASC, NXT.orderno ASC "
```

(Apologies if this code has syntax errors, I have not been able to test it)

If orderno is always a number, you could omit the quote marks around strCurrentOrder.

Comment: I will try your recommendation on Monday first thing in the morning, right now I do not have access to the network from home, lamentably.